# How to change the protocol from http to https in AWS ELB load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

Is it possible at all to change the protocol and port of the **Target Group** created using AWS Load Balancer.

For instance, if I have set up initially `HTTPS:443` as the protocol:port for my ELB and then I want to change it to `HTTP:80` — how can I do that? Or do I have to delete everything and set up a new load balancer with the new settings and new target groups?

Answer (score 4):

This is **not possible** for changing the target group protocol itself.

You can change the health checks, but the target group appears to not be modifiable.

You would need to create a fresh target group with the protocol/port combination you want and then update the listener to use the new target group.

If however you want to change the listener (this is the client to load balancer connection) then you can modify or create a new listener at any time.

This can be modified either through the console or through the CLI using the [modify-listener](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/elbv2/modify-listener.html) function.

Answer (score 0):

As the question tag with `Amazon Elastic Load Balancing (ELB)` and also you mentioned **ELB** elastic load balancer then you there is **no target group but instances** so you can just update the listener only.

You can modify an existing listener.

- Select LB
- Select Listener
- Modify port

[image]

Or if **ALB**  then you can not update target group but you can add new the same instance with updated `PORT`. But better to create New target group and update target in the listener so it will be use by new instance launch in this target group.

To add an instance with a different port in this target group

- Remove existing instance
- Add the same instance with the new port

[image]